# Sherry Wine vs Sherry Vinegar

Tags: substitutions, vinegar

Is sherry wine the same as sherry vinegar? My recipe calls for sherry vinegar and I currently have sherry cooking wine. Can I use it?

Comment: Probably not. vinegar is, erm, vinegar; I would try substituting with another type of vinegar (red wine or cider vinegar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really. Sherry vinegar is made *from* sherry wine. It is naturally more acidic in flavour. You are better off substituting another vinegar such as white wine, cider or balsamic.

Comment: Especially do not *ever* substitute in the other direction.  Using vinegar in place of wine would be an easy way to ruin a dish.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't taste the same, then they're not the same :)

You might be able to get a similar effect by using regular vinegar and sherry wine, in a ratio of aboutttt 3:1?  Maybe some others can comment on the ratio here.

You may find that white vinegar is a bit strong though.